# Query regarding permission for Indian to work as postdoc in UK

Tags: postdocs, visa

I am applying for a Postdoc in an UK University. They are asking whether I have permission to work in UK. How can I know my eligibility to work as Postdoc in UK? What type of visa issued by UK for postdocs?

Detail:

> The University of Bath is a sponsor under the Points Based System. Where there are no suitable applicants from within the EEA, we may, depending on the position, be able to issue a Certificate of Sponsorship.
>   For further information, please refer to the UK Border Agency website (new window).
>
> Please select one of the following options*
>
> - I am a British Citizen/EEA National.
> - I am not a British Citizen/EEA National and I am not currently eligible to work in the UK.
> - I am not a British Citizen/EEA National, but I am eligible to work in the UK. Please give the reason below.

Comment: @scaaahu - subtly different, I think, but will answer & point to that

Answer (score 5):

The EEA is the EU plus a number of other European countries (eg Norway) whose citizens have employment rights in the UK. Assuming you're not a dual citizen, option 1 won't apply to you.

If you do not have any reason to assume you are eligible to work in the UK (eg you don't already have a UK work visa) then you should tick **opiton 2** - "I am not currently eligible". It is very unlikely that you would have eligibility without already knowing the reasons for it (eg "I already have a work visa").

Then (as @scaaahu says) read [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/46778/27825) to find out how the system works after this point. The important thing to remember is that the university is potentially able to sponsor you to get a visa, so ticking "no" won't stop the application. If they decide to take you, they will be able to take care of the visa issues.

Good luck with the application.